# Finding The Most Relevant or Important Features for SVM using SGD (loss=hinge)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, sklearn-pandas

I am working on a text-classification problem and have found that SVM is performing best for my text-classification problem. However, I did my experiment using sklearn's SGD classifier (loss=hinge).

[LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) seems to provide a way to analyze the instance and show the analysis for each class given an instance. However, the problem with LIME is:

```
exp = explainer.explain_instance(test_document, c.predict_proba)
```

in the explainer.explain_instance function, it requires a probability distribution as the second parameter (c.predict_proba) and there is no predict_proba available for SGD (loss=hinge). I have tried using CalibratedClassifierCV but I am getting different results with it.

```
'=======SGD (loss=hinge)======='
Predicted:  [19, 7, 7, 13, 16, 9, 17, 6, 13, 17, 16, 17, 11, 1, 4, 14, 8, 10, 12, 10, 16, 1, 1]
True     :  [19, 3, 7, 13, 16, 9, 15, 6, 13, 10, 16, 17, 11, 1, 4, 14, 8, 5, 20, 18, 2, 12, 1]
0.6521739130434783
'====Calibrated Results======'
Predicted:  [19, 7, 7, 13, 16, 16, 12, 6, 13, 17, 16, 17, 11, 5, 4, 14, 8, 10, 15, 10, 16, 7, 1]
True     :  [19, 3, 7, 13, 16, 9, 15, 6, 13, 10, 16, 17, 11, 1, 4, 14, 8, 5, 20, 18, 2, 12, 1]
0.5652173913043478
```

The objective here is to find the most relevant/important features for each class in a multi-class text-classification problem. The purpose of this is to analyze the results and discuss their differences in a research paper. 
Open to any suggestions or alternatives.

Also, I could possibly use sklearn's SVC instead of SGD as it has the predict_proba attribute. However, the problem is with SGD I already have a set of parameters for which I am doing the analysis and I couldn't find a way to exactly convert the SGD's configuration to SVC's configuration.

Comment: Out of interest, how many folds did you use in CalibratedClassifierCV?

Comment: I kept it to the default value (cv=3). My dataset is small and therefore, I can't go above 5

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't make LIME work, but I found an alternative to LIME, called [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn-text.html) a python's library. I'll recreate an example from the tutorial website as to how this module can be used to debug a machine learning algorithm.

Assuming you already have a sklearn's clf or estimator object that is fitted on a vectorized text data:

```
import eli5
eli5.show_weights(clf, top=10)
```

[image]

The code above works, but a better way is to provide vectorizer instead and let eli5 figure out the details automatically:

```
#vec is the vectorizer object and 
#target_names is the names of the classes to be used
eli5.show_weights(clf, vec=vec, top=10,
                  target_names=twenty_test.target_names)
```

[image]

To look into how the classifier assigned a particular class *show_prediction* shows the scores for each class with top words that contributed to that score

```
#second param is the test instance whose prediction you'd like to see.
#vec and target_names are same from show_weights 
eli5.show_prediction(clf, twenty_test.data[0], vec=vec,
                     target_names=twenty_test.target_names)
```

The following is only part of the entire output produced through *show_prediction* method.
[image]

This is exactly what I was looking for, I wonder why I didn't find it before. Hope it helps others looking for something similar.